# Execution error on with statement, but before all ran good

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I used this macro a few days ago and all worked well but now it does not work properly. I get an execution error at the very beginning  of the with statement, or i get another automation error.

I checked if my file exists and it exists, checked if it's found or not: all ok but when i create the excel object and begin with statement i get an error

```
    ActiveDocument.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim strSite As Site, intRow As Long, rg As Object, tmp As String, lastCol As Long, i As Long  'varibles pour derniere colonne du fichier excel et la ligne de la trigramme recherche
    Dim xlapp As Object, xlbook As Object, currentcell As Object, nextcell As Object, src As Object
    Dim found As String, filename
    'creation du objet Excel
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If err Then
        Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    filename = "FichierTrigrammes.xlsx"
    found = Dir(folderPath & "\" & "FichierTrigrammes.xlsx")
    MsgBox found
    If found <> vbNullString Then

    ' to be changed to the real File Name, if not it will not work
        Set xlbook = xlapp.workbooks.Open(filename:=folderPath & filename): xlapp.Visible = False  'does not open the file, read only => faster to get the info
        ' searching for the Trigramm

        With xlbook.sheets(1)

            intRow = xlbook.sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:=strTrigram).Row 
            'getting the address -> to get the row therafter
            'find the last non blank cell in specific row
            Set currentcell = xlbook.sheets(1).Range("a" & intRow)
            Do While Not IsEmpty(currentcell)
                Set nextcell = currentcell.Offset(0, 1)
                If nextcell.Value = currentcell.Value Then
                    currentcell.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                Set currentcell = nextcell
            Loop
            lastCol = .Range(currentcell.Address).Column
            For i = 1 To lastCol
                Select Case .Cells(1, i).Value
                    Case "Type Site"
                        strSite.type = .Cells(intRow, i).Value
                    Case "Nom Site"
                        strSite.nomSite = .Cells(intRow, i).Value
                End Select
            Next i
        End With

       'Set xlapp = Nothing: Set xlbook = Nothing                        ' pour ne pas sauvegarder le document
    End If
    ActiveDocument.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    getSiteInfo = strSite
End Function
```

Comment: Which error and in which line of code? What is `strTrigram`? Please see what a [mcve] is and provide the necessary code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I do apologies i forgot to mention that. So, 'strTrigram' is string ID for something that i cant tell you what. The error i get is "Execution error 91, object variable or  bloc variable WITH not defiened" (i tried to translate it in english) and it appears at line <code> With xlbook.sheets(1) <\code>   or at line   <code> intRow = xlbook.sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:=strTrigram).Row </code>.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Also the other error i get is "erreur d'execution -2147418111 erreur automation. l'appel a été rejeté par l'appelé"  idk how to translate it and it happens at <code> Set xlbook = xlapp.workbooks.Open(filename:=folderPath & filename) </code>

Comment: Actually you cannot get both errors because VBA stops excecution after the first error. So you need to be more clear here what exactly happens when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First issue

1. If you use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) it might be that nothing is found so you will always need to test for that case.
2. You need **always** to specify the `LookAt` parameter for `Find` as `xlWhole` or `xlPart` otherwise VBA will use whatever the user or VBA used before (there is no default). If you don't specify it you never know what you get.

So something like this:

```
Dim FoundAt As Range

'…
FoundAt = xlbook.sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=strTrigram, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then '
    intRow = FoundAt.Row 

    'All your other code
Else
    MsgBox "'" & strTrigram & "' was not found."
End If
```

If you use `Late Binding` in Word then define the following constants:

```
Const xlWhole As Long = 1
Const xlPart As Long = 2
```

to make them available in Word.

---

#### Second issue

Note that with the following code both `Set xlapp` might fail and both errors will be hidden because of `On Error Resume Next`.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If err Then
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Change it to

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If xlapp Is Nothing Then
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
```

---

#### Third issue

You test if `folderPath & "\" & "FichierTrigrammes.xlsx"` exists but you open something different `folderPath & filename`.

Change it to

```
filename = "FichierTrigrammes.xlsx"
found = Dir(folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & filename)
```

and use that to open the file

```
Set xlbook = xlapp.workbooks.Open(filename:=folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & filename)
```

Comment: The thing is that what i m looking for i know it exists, i have to do a find to know the row. Also I tried  to add xlWhole or xlPart but it does not work, word does not recognize it (maybe cause i'm coding in word vba and create an Excel object?)

Comment: Ah of course if you are coding in Word and you use `Late Binding` then replace `xlWhole` with `1` or `xlPart` with `2`. or define them as constants as in my edited answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Yeah that is my problem i'm coding in Word and it's annoying

Comment: Thanks it solved one problem. I still got the problem with  "Execution Error-2147418111 Automation Error. call rejected by the caller" (something like that in english) and it happens at the line `Set xlbook = xlapp.workbooks.Open(filename:=folderPath & filename): xlapp.Visible = False`

Comment: @RagingDeathWish First split that into 2 lines at the colon `:` so we know if the first or second part throws that error. Also check what the `folderPath & filename` in case of error is. Check if the file exists and try to open it manually in Excel to see if it is not corrupt or something.

Comment: I tried to use ` Dir(folderpath & "\" & filename) ` and if it's not found then it does nothing, but i still get the error at the same line when opening the file. It's the first part that's causing the error

Comment: @RagingDeathWish Can you open this file manually? Also see my edited answer.

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ yes i can open the file manually, i just saw your answer i did not knew it. Even so, the error is still here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196635/discussion-between-p-and-ragingdeathwish).